# AspectJ not working after Transaction configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-transactions

Firstly i had a problem with Transactions not working so i updated the configutation from `@EnableTransactionManagement` to `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)`, but after the update this bug is thrown at launch.

[image]

after commenting all code related to AspectJ, the bugs disappears and the transaction is working perfectly, but i'm missing my AspectJ functions.

i've tried to replace `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)` by `@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.PROXY)` and by  `@EnableTransactionManagement @EnableLoadTimeWeaving`, none of them let me use AspectJ, using the debugger i can see that the advice is not executed at all.

**AppConfig.java**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.geopro" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.geopro.repositories" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.geopro.entities" })
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)//(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)//
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
         HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
         factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
         return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: When using `mode=ASPECTJ` you will need to use compile or lead-time weaving to have your aspects woven in. So enabling just aspectj is a bit more difficult then what you have now.

Comment: now i'm using `(proxyTargetClass=true)`, i'm looking to  AOP and transactions by anymatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moral of the story is **Never mix Transactions and AspectJ functions in the same class**, i've learned that the hard way, Transaction uses in its internals AOP, its AOP don't play well with user AOP.